# Route 53 not failing over

Tags: amazon-route53

I've got 2 servers set up for a small web app. 
Primary A is 1.1.1.1
Secondary A is 2.2.2.2

All dns is through R53 and I have a functioning health check setup.

Traffic does currently flow to 1.1.1.1 correctly.

When the health check says unhealthy the dns should resolve the A record to the second A record but it does not.

The TTL is set to 60 secs but I've given it an hour and still nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so when setting up the association of the health check, you only associate the primary record.

Associating the secondary record makes it unavailable as well.

:)